# How do I become an Administrator of my own Ubuntu machines?

Tags: 22.04, administrator

I have several Ubuntu machines for learning purposes. They are on old laptops from family members.

How do I become an Admin for these laptops. I want to update them from my machine, I want to create users and block users, all the things admins do?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu, you created an user during installation. That user is the administrator. Learn how to use the `sudo` command on the command line to do all the things admins do.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Ubuntu machines do have a *root* user (the Linux / Unix name of the allmighty system administrator), but no password is set for that account, so you can't log in with that user name.

The way you do that is to use the `sudo` command which allows you to run one single command with *root* privileges. The first user account that was created on that machine during system installation is normally set up to use `sudo`. You will have to supply the password of that normal user account when requested.

```
sudo someprivilegedcommand --and-its-arguments
```

...system asks for a password - enter your user password here...

...privileged command is executed...

...you are back to your normal non-privileged shell session.

But I would really recommend you to read some books or web tutorials or watch some videos on basic Linux operation; otherwise you are very likely to shoot yourself in the foot, much more so with *root* privileges.